Bibmacro not fully printed?
I am trying to set up the legislation entry type, so it will print
Title (date or year). Author: Website-Title. url (last accessed: urldate).
I am using this piece of code
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LAYOUT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  %parskip,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
\usepackage{hyphenat}% create hypen without overfull box

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TOC
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\KOMAoptions{toc=sectionentrydotfill}
\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}% correct TOC count for tables
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{TOC}
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{{\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}}}% TOC in bookmarks
\AddtoDoHook{heading/preinit/part}{\clearpage\vspace*{\stretch{1}}}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/part}{\vspace*{\stretch{2}}\clearpage}
\setkomafont{partprefix}{\usekomafont{part}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIB
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  alldates=terse,
  url=false,
]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearlist{language}%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}% avoid bib formatting issues

% editor in parentheses
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}

% set law type UNFINISHED
% legislative
\DeclareFieldFormat[legislation]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[legislation]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{legislationformat}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{publisher}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{legislation}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{legislationformat}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}
  }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\nocite{*} 
\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}

And this bib entry
@legislation{BundesministeriumderJustiz.2021-GesetzuberUrheberrecht,
    abstract = {Gesetz {\"u}ber Urheberrecht und verwandte Schutzrechte (Urheberrechtsgesetz)},
    author = {{Bundesministerium der Justiz}},
    date = {2021-06-07},
    publisher = {Gesetze im Internet},
    title = {Gesetz {\"u}ber Urheberrecht und verwandte Schutzrechte (Urheberrechtsgesetz)},
    url = {https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/},
    urldate = {2024-08-24}}

Unfortunately the publisher and date are not printed at all. 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong

The \print... macros are data-type specific. So just as you need e.g. \printnames for author because author takes names, so you need the appropriate \print... invocations for dates and publishers.
publisher is a list, so use \printlist. For dates, use \printdate.
The reason you get nothing is that e.g. date doesn't exist by the time you do \printfield because date gets split up and mapped to e.g. year, month etc.
